# Sum of the series $\sum u_n$ where $u_n=\frac{\sqrt{(n-1)!}}{(1+\sqrt{1}) \dots (1+\sqrt{n})}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

While I'm able to prove that the series $u_n=\frac{\sqrt{(n-1)!}}{(1+\sqrt{1}) \dots (1+\sqrt{n})}$ converges, I don't see the trick to compute the value of its sum starting at $n=2$.

**Any clue on the way to compute the sum?**

Comment: Do you need the value, or only whether it converges? Those are very different questions.

Comment: I need the value.

Comment: There is $$u_{n+1}=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{1+\sqrt{n+1}}u_n = \left(1-\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{1+\sqrt{n+1}}\right)u_n$$ Not sure if that helps

Comment: If you need the exact value, then you probably need to tell us $\sum_{n=1}^\infty$ or what the starting index is.

Comment: Let say starting at $n=2$.

Comment: Then the value is $\frac12$.

Comment: And what is the method to get $\frac{1}{2}$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Lemma**: For $n>1$, one has $u_n\sqrt n -u_{n-1}\sqrt{n-1}=-u_n$.

**Proof**: We have
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{u_n\sqrt n} -\color{red}{u_{n-1}\sqrt{n-1}}=\frac{\sqrt{(n-1)!}}{\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(1+\sqrt k)}\left[\color{blue}{\frac{\sqrt n}{1+\sqrt{n}}}-\color{red}{1}\right]=-u_n.
\end{align*}
**Corollary**: Our sum is telescoping. Indeed,
$$\sum_{n=2}^N u_n=\sum_{n=2}^N \left(u_{n-1}\sqrt{n-1}-u_n\sqrt n\right)
=u_1-u_N\sqrt N.$$
Furthermore one can show that $u_N\sqrt{N}\to 0$ as $N\to\infty$, and therefore
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{n=2}^N u_n=u_1=\frac12.$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{eqnarray*} \log(u_n) &=& \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\log(\sqrt{k})-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\log(1+\sqrt{k})\\&=&-\log(1+\sqrt{n})-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\log\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\right)\\&\leq&-\log(1+\sqrt{n})-\log(2)\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\end{eqnarray*}$$
hence $u_n$ behaves like $4^{-\sqrt{n}}$, leading to a clearly summable sequence.

Comment: In fact my question is to find the value of the sum.